# NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type Expected JSONPaymentCard but found __NSDictionaryI

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, jsonmodel

I am using JSONModel to cast values from server:

```
@interface PaymentCardsResponse: JSONModel
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray<JSONPaymentCard *> *userCards;
@end
```

But when later I try to access this

```
response.userCards.forEach { card in } //here is an error
```

I have an error:

> Precondition failed: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type
> Expected JSONPaymentCard but found __NSDictionaryI

Why do I have it there? What am I missing?

Comment: `NSDictionary` objects seem to have been put inside the `userCards` array, rather than `JSONPaymentCard`. Can you show the code that puts things into `userCards`? Are you using `JSONSerialization`? That tends to creates `NSDictionary`s.

Comment: `[[PaymentCardsResponse alloc] initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *) responseBody error:error];` This is how I parse response body.

Comment: And... what does that do exactly? Please show a [mcve].

Comment: This is the custom init from library. That is all I do with this. You want example response?

Comment: Oh I see, "JSONModel" is the name of a library! I added the tag for you :) They seem to have explained this clearly in the README: "Note: the angle brackets after NSArray contain a protocol. **This is not the same as the Objective-C generics system.** They are not mutually exclusive, but for JSONModel to work, the protocol must be in place."

Comment: So perhaps try `NSArray<JSONPaymentCard *> <JSONPaymentCard> *userCards;`. That's what they did in the README file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [README](https://github.com/jsonmodel/jsonmodel/blob/master/README.md) file of JSONModel, there is a note saying:

> ```
> @interface OrderModel : JSONModel
> @property (nonatomic) NSInteger orderId;
> @property (nonatomic) float totalPrice;
> @property (nonatomic) NSArray <ProductModel> *products;
> @end
> ```
>
> Note: the angle brackets after NSArray contain a protocol. This is not the same as the Objective-C generics system. They are not mutually exclusive, but for JSONModel to work, the protocol must be in place.

JSONModel uses the type in the `<>` to determine the specific type of array to deserialise, and it is specifically noted that you can't replace this with Objective-C generics system ("not the same"!), so if you did:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray<JSONPaymentCard *> *userCards;
```

You are not telling JSONModel what model type the array should contain, so it just dumbly deserialises `NSDictionary`s. You can do both Objective-C generics, *and* tell JSONModel the type of the array, as demonstrated by the next code snippet in the README.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray<JSONPaymentCard *> <JSONPaymentCard> *userCards;
```